# How did they film the changing decks in the turbolift scenes in Star Trek: TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes

I noticed in S04E01 "The Best Of Both Worlds: Part 2" (at 08:20 when Riker and Worf enter the turbolift), there is a black opening at the end of the hallway, however when they reach engineering there is a orange door on the end of the hallway, indicating they've reached another section of the ship and a different decor. How did they achieve this?

Did they have an actual lift mechanism? Did they turn it around? Did they quickly change decor while they where filming the scene? Note that the scene in question was *continuous* and did not use the "freeze" command as used in some other scenes (h/t to @Zeiss Ikon)

Comment: "Freeze" command like they used to use for transporter sequences?

Comment: https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/turbolifts-and-dual-sets-of-doors.35799/ might be interesting.

Comment: Also interesting, https://forgottentrek.com/creating-star-treks-first-bridge/, but not as illustrative about turbolift operation.

Comment: what is "h/t Zeiss Ikon" ?

Comment: @JDługosz hat tip to Zeiss Ikon for noting that I did not specify there was a "freeze" command like they used in other scenes

Comment: Why would that have needed anything more than a trivial moving background?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

According to [Memory-Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_(episode)#Production), which lists as source the [Star Trek: Fan Collective - Borg DVD set](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Fan_Collective_-_Borg) text commentary:

> Cliff Bole filmed the scene wherein Riker and Worf share an elevator
> trip – from one corridor to another – in one continuous shot, using a
> subtle lighting difference in the corridor set to make it seem as if
> the turbolift (which did not actually move) had traveled between two
> different corridors. An alcove at the far end of the corridor is dark
> when the characters enter the lift but lit when they exit. (Star Trek:
> Fan Collective - Borg text commentary)

Comment: Thanks this is a very good answer. I will wait the customary day or two before accepting but this has answered it.

Comment: I'm reminded of a description of how they moved the TARDIS back in the older Doctor Who episodes - they just picked the whole thing up with a forklift and drove it to where it needed to be.  But then they never had to handle being able to enter, transport somewhere/when and then leave in one continuous shot.  And it wasn't until the reboot show that you ever got to see outside the TARDIS from inside or vice versa, by which point they had CGI and other more advanced techniques at their disposal.

Comment: there you go - the magic of TV... they switched on a light.

Answer (score 71):

Taking into account that the background setting is identical, it looks like they simply altered the lighting slightly between the time that Riker and Worf walk into the lift and then walked out again.

The door in the background is a dark umber colour when they walk in and then lighter orange when they walk out, an effect that would be achieved by merely [illuminating the door slightly](https://colorswall.com/palette/35061/).

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, you where certainly fast :). I will go for dennis_vok's answer because he has reference material, but I wish I could accept them both!

Comment: @TomSol - His is certainly the better answer but I'll be updating the picture later with a better image quality.

Comment: I wish we could merge answers, your image comparison is great!

Comment: @Valorum at the time of this answer your were looking for an 'image slider' feature to make the comparison interactive. It exists here: https://imgsli.com/MTAxNzM3 . Found it via this article: https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/333150-i-can-restore-star-trek-voyager-and-deep-space-nine-to-hd-so-why-cant-paramount